# There was a bomb threat at my building and they didn't tell us about it and forced us to stay where we were

Tags: canada, police

I had worked for the federal government in a building they owned. On a couple occasions all the doors leading to different floors where closed and locked. We were told to stay in our offices. I latter found out "some suspicious matterial had been discovered near the enterance and though the police couldn't be certain of what it was at the time had advised us to treat it as a potential bomb threat". This was all very strange.

1. They did not inform us of the reason until after the doors were unlocked
2. They forced us to stay on the floor we were in, in the building and not exit the building

Are the above 2 legal? Is this more of a question for The Work Place? I was on the third floor and the alleged threat was on the first but I thought if there's a bomb they would want everyone out of the building...

Must an employer tell you if there's a bomb?

Comment: When you say "they", to whom are you referring?

Comment: @NateEldredge anyone, but I remember on at least one occasion a coworker saying we weren't allowed to talk about why the building was under lock down...though some people did know and where gossiping about it.

Comment: @Dawn just the potential, they never actually found a bomb.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak for Canada but in Australia, yes, you must be told.

This stems from the obligation a Person Controlling a Business or Undertaking (PCBU) to consult with their workers and other PCBUs about Work Health and Safety risks. A bomb or even a bomb threat would definitely count as a Work Health and Safety Risk.

However, *when* and *how* they tell you would depend on the circumstances. In the middle of responding to the emergency may not be the safest or most appropriate time. Once the crisis has passed and the facts have been established they would be obliged to consult so that their workers' could understand the risk and help develop policies and procedures with coping with future events.

This may not take the form of one-on-one communication; it could be through Work Health and Safety Representatives, emails, bulletin boards or whatever has been agreed in your workplace.

Comment: I think you're a cool dude that posts good answers, but I notice that on a lot of questions you ignore the region entirely and post an "in Australia" answer.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire yes, I write what I know, I try not to speculate on what I don't. Questions are a resource for everyone, not just the OP; the next person who searches the site with this problem might just be Australian.

Comment: True, that makes sense I post like that on other SE sites.